# Transfer Objects between state machines

Tags: java, spring, spring-statemachine

Is it generally possible to transfer data, eg. strings or more generally objects, between two state machines.

Imagine the following situation:

I'm using serveral state machines with almost the same business logic. 
My idea is to extract the same business logic in one state machine and connect it to the other ones. The state machines may have an incoming and an outcoming area to connect them to each other. It could also be a more generally abstract state machine. I think this situation describes my idea at is best (SM means state machine):

- SM_1 --> SM_0 --> SM_2
- SM_3 --> SM_0 --> SM_4 (whereas SM_0 is always the same state machine)
- SM_0 --> SM_6
- etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to get what you are trying to explain with the below schema, but if you want to pass state, you should serialize your objects (in JSON format for example, using [Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial) might be a great idea here), then you could actually pass that same string between your different States Machines and unserialize it. As your post is quite vague, I'm not sure we can help you more without further context and explanations about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: It's not really this, want I like to achieve. I like to do the following: Doing any stuff in statemachine 1, after that doing stuff in statemachine 0 and afterwards doing stuff in statemachine 2. Exactly this, what I described above. The strickting point is that i want to connect any statemachine before and after statemachine 0 without serizlise my objects, just having them on the heap. 
Sorry, for my bad description.

Comment: Hum, are all of your machines running on a single JVM or are they running on separate environment ? If they don't share the same JVM, then your only option is object serialization, which is the only way to pass objects from a context to another one. Serialization might take several forms, so it might be something easier than json serialization if your context is simple enough.

Comment: They run on the same JVM

Comment: Is there any kind of common application context you could share between them then ? How does your code looks like ? Are those state machines separate threads ?

Comment: Yes there is common application context between them. I dont think that my code does actually help you, because its a more a design problem of spring-state machines rather than a code problem. The state machines could be on seperate threads. like a normal web server.

Comment: If they could be on separate servers, then you would have to go through serialization and JSON is a great serialization candidate here because you could make this available through a REST API standard gateway between your Spring apps, and easily send and retrieve the objects between each machine. The network side of your task seems quite more complex though because all of those state machines will probably be in the same subnet, hidden behind a load balancer or something like this, and in this sense, having a master / slaves pattern might be an option for you.

Comment: Tank you very much, by the way!